# Using aggregate to get the mean of duplicate rows in a data.frame in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a matrix `B` that is 10 rows x 2 columns:

```
B = matrix(c(1:20), nrow=10, ncol=2)
```

Some of the rows are technical duplicates, and they correspond to the same 
number in a list of length 20 (list1).

```
list1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8)
list1 = as.list(list1)
```

I would like to use this list (list1) to take the mean of any duplicate values for all columns in `B` such that I end up with a matrix or data.frame with 8 rows and 2 columns (all the duplicates are averaged).

Here is my code:

```
aggregate.data.frame(B, by=list1, FUN=mean)
```

And it generates this error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(B, by = list1, FUN = mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I am confused, you want to take out the duplicates, then get the mean of those?

Answer (score 0):

Your data have 2 variables (2 columns), each with 10 observations (10 rows). The function `aggregate.data.frame` expects the elements in the list to have the same length as the number of observations in your variables. You are getting an error because the vector in your list has 20 values, while you only have 10 observations per variable. So, for example, you can do this because now you have 1 variable with 20 observations, and list 1 has a vector with 20 elements.

```
B <- 1:20
list1 <- list(B=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,8,8)) 
aggregate.data.frame(B, by=list1, FUN=mean)
```

The code will also work if you give it a matrix with 2 columns and 20 rows.

```
aggregate.data.frame(cbind(B,B), by=list1, FUN=mean)
```

I think this answer addresses why you are getting an error. However, I am not sure that it addresses what you are actually trying to do. How do you expect to end up with 8 rows and 2 columns? What exactly would the cells in that matrix represent?